# Turn an ascii character code to a value between 0-26

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, ascii

Hello everyone today I have a question concerning the math involved in turning ascii code into a value between 0-26.

With lowercase letters it's simply the characters code - 65. However if I run into capital letters it's no longer the case.

I was wondering what would be the algorithm for converting any letters ascii code into a value between 0-26

Comment: Start by converting the text to lowercase.

Comment: I thought of that but I would ideally like to preserve the state of each letters.

Comment: How can you simultaneously preserve the case and convert each letters, being `a` or `A` for instance, to an unique number, `1` in the example?

Comment: Can you be specific as to what platform you're talking about here?  You're talking about at least three, all of which are ***massively*** divergent between themselves.  Are you working in C#, PHP, or Objective-C?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to count the amount of letters in a string but without the need of  converting to lowercase. Using math. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok. I'll be more specific. Like I said above I'm trying to count the amount of occurrences for each letter in a given string without using to_lowercase.

Comment: Since when is ios a language? Anyway, take a look at the ASCII-table, and it's a trivial exercise: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work in C and C++:

```
int codeFor(char ch) {
   if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
      return ch - 'A';
   } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
      return ch - 'a';
   } else {
      /* do something to report an error. */
   }
}
```

Notice that there are no constants like 65 in this program - character literals are a lot easier to use for these purposes.

Hope this helps!